# How can I ensure security with cURL?

Tags: php, curl, security

I've got a cURL setup that transfers data from one server to another.  How can I prevent people from running the cURL code just by browsing to the URL?  Is there some way to detect what's calling the code?

Comment: Euh, make a filename like "oubivu456er87bcv.php"?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you force them to authenticate before the script is executed? There is not really a big difference between securing that, and any secure content on the web.